# CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls not an option

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I thinking how can I fix it my debug error without CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false
I know, It's a bad thing, so how can I fix my code? Here is an example:

```
Private Sub tim1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tim1.Tick

     BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
end sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

  Dim inStream As StreamReader
        Dim webRequest As WebRequest
        Dim webresponse As WebResponse
        webRequest = webRequest.Create("https://website.com/stuff=100&id=" + ListBox2.Text)
        DirectCast(webRequest, HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)"
        webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
        inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
        TextBox5.Text = inStream.ReadToEnd()
        For Each m As Match In New Regex("""(?<=href="")([^""]+)").Matches(TextBox5.Text)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(m.Value + "@website.com,")
        Next
        Try
            correct()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        For index = Me.ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If Me.ListBox2.FindStringExact(Me.ListBox1.GetItemText(Me.ListBox2.Items(index))) <> index Then
                Me.ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(index)
            End If
        Next
        For index = Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If Me.ListBox1.FindStringExact(Me.ListBox1.GetItemText(Me.ListBox1.Items(index))) <> index Then
                Me.ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
            End If
        Next
        Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count

end sub
```

Error message:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: 
Control 'ListBox2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Part of problem: `webRequest = webRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=" + ListBox2.Text)`

Comment: I see accessing gui objects (ListBox1) in a background thread.  That's the problem.  You need to bubble that information up to the gui thread.  Don't use empty try-catch blocks.  The exception information is your friend, don't ignore it.

Comment: @LarsTech - Also accessing `TextBox5` too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving the response stream into `TextBox5.Text`, save it in `e.Result`:

```
e.Result = inStream.ReadToEnd()
```

Move the code after that point into a handler for [`BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This will run on the UI thread, and you can make your updates to the UI there.

You will also need to pass in any UI information that is used in `DoWork` (e.g. `ListBox2.Text`) as parameters:

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(ListBox2.Text)
```

Comment: If I put my code to BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted then my UI is freezing.

Comment: @sandor What is the interval set for on that timer?

Comment: 1000 ms. Why u asking?

Comment: @sandor Since you accepted, hopefully you got it working, but only the UI code goes in `RunWorkedCompleted` - the `WebRequest` code stays in `DoWork`, which is presumably the long-running code.